# CSS for Wordpress Customizr Theme Navigation Hover Animation

Tags: css, wordpress, navigationbar

I've been racking my head over this seemingly little thing for a while but I'm at my wits end. I'm running a free Customizr theme on my site.

What I am trying to achieve is to have the [hover effect in the navigation bar like this demo here.](https://demo.presscustomizr.com/) As you can see, *only* the text of the dropdown menu items are nicely underlined.

I've found and tried to use this CSS code here:

```
.sliding-middle a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.sliding-middle a:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
}
.sliding-middle a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: #08c;
}
```

However, the result I got [as you can see here](https://saveyfox.com), the dropdown menu items are underlined all the way across. I found that if I didn't target the "a" tags, the line would appear even more weirdly on the main menu items. But by doing so, the whole submenus inherit this effect.

If anyone has any idea what I'm missing, please help me out. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! After a few days of stressing it out and breaking my site, I've finally sort-of solved this issue.

Firstly, as @janh2 mentioned, you need to get the page to add `span` tags to the navigation menu labels. I've asked a different question and [have updated it with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46642734/8739471).

Next it's simply using the following to get the result:

```
.sliding-middle span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.sliding-middle span:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
}
.sliding-middle span:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: black; /*colour you want your line to be*/
```

I hope this helps guys.

Answer (score 0):

The example you want to achieve uses two span-nodes inside the a and only targets the first one (adding a pseudo :before) with this CSS

```
.header-skin-light [class*=nav__menu] li>a>span:first-of-type:hover::before {
    background-color: #313131;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scaleX(1);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scaleX(1);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scaleX(1);
}
```

If you add a span for the link text, you should get pretty much the same result.

Comment: Thanks, janh2. Yes, I did notice the span tags. However, I have no idea how to add the span to the individual links as the nav bar is generated by the theme. Also, are the -webkit- and -moz- properties compulsory?

Comment: Have you created a child theme (you should if you want to change stuff)? If the menu is generated using `wp_nav_menu()` (it usually is), you'll be able to use a [custom walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) to alter the output and add the span you require.

Comment: Yes, I am using a child theme for all customisations. Sorry but I'm really lost about this. After Googling a bit about Custom walker to put span into a tags, I get a wall of code I can't make heads or tails of. What I understand so far is that I can use the walker to edit 'wp_nav_menu' and somehow push the span into the a tag.

Comment: Thinking about it, you might get by with `"link_before" => "<span>", "link_after" => "</span>"`. Those go into the arguments for wp_nav_menu(). Post how `wp_nav_menu()` is called in your theme if you run into problems.

Comment: Alright I tried `wp_nav_menu(array("link_before" => "<span>", "link_after" => "</span>"));` and it broke the site, and the dropdowns seem to just appear on screen altogether. I was fortunate to get this error one time if it means anything: "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php:256) in /public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210" pluggable.php 1210 is `header("Location: $location", true, $status);`

Comment: Errrm, it shouldn't break anything :( Did you put that in your functions.php or similar instead of header.php, and what does the working call wo wp_nav_menu() look like?

Comment: Yes I added it to the child theme functions.php. I don't know what you mean by working call. If you meant the normal look, it's as you see now.

Comment: Putting it directly in the functions.php will call it too early (hence the errors). Look for the place where the wp_nav_menu() is called now (probably header.php in the theme), and replace that with the new version (or add the two parameters to the working version).

Comment: Ah I see. How can I find the place it's called now? It's not in the header.php of the main theme. But then if I were to edit it in the child theme, would I need to create another one of the same file and enqueue that too?

Comment: Just search all files in the theme folder with your file manager. If they don't use wp_nav_menu (which I doubt), search for something related to the menu, e.g. `tc-hover-menu`, as that's the class for the menu. Whether you have to create a copy of that file: depends. If they do that in an action hook, you can just remove that and add your own. But find it first ;)

Comment: I found `wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => czr_fn_get_property( 'theme_location' ),
    'container'       => null,
    'menu_class'      => czr_fn_get_property( 'menu_class' ),
    'fallback_cb'     => czr_fn_get_property( 'fallback_cb' ),
    'walker'          => czr_fn_get_property( 'walker' ),
    'menu_id'         => czr_fn_get_property( 'menu_id' ),
    'link_before'     => '<span>',
    'link_after'      => '</span>',
    'dropdown_type'   => czr_fn_get_property( 'dropdown_type' )
  ) );` in the menu.php in the parent theme folder. Why doesn't the span get pushed in?

Comment: `'walker' => czr_fn_get_property( 'walker' )` might be the reason, as that sets the Walker WordPress should use to create the output. If they have implemented a custom walker, it might ignore those options. what does `get_class(czr_fn_get_property( 'walker' ))` produce?

Comment: Unsure what walker does but then I've edited the nav-menu file to default `span` before and after link. Works like a charm now.