# Wordpress Customizr theme Adding span to navigation "a" tags breaks site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I posted another question about CSS but came to the solution of adding span tags to the title of the links in the navigation menu. What I have is:

```
<div>
  <li>
    <a>
      About me
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

I wanted something like:

```
<div>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span>
         About me
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Then I found that I could probably try using

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'link_before' => '<span>',
    'link_after'  => '</span>'
  ) 
);
```

This proceeded to break my site, causing all menu dropdown items to simply display on screen in addition to the "normal" nav bar I have.

The error I got was: **"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php:256) in /public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210"**

nav-menu-template.php 256 is `echo $nav_menu;`

pluggable.php 1210 is `header("Location: $location", true, $status);`

I'm at my wits end. Anyone who remotely knows what's going on, please help. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you see the last comment I left on your other question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, I finally got it.

I just edited this file:

`public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php`

Within you will see `$defaults` and you should simply edit `link_before` and `link_after`:

`$defaults = array( ...'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>', ...);`

This should get the theme to push `<span>NAVIGATION LABEL</span>` into all your nav menu items.

Hope this helps.